# Can't free memory from struct member variables

Tags: c

After I call `free` on a struct variable in C, and then check if that variable is NULL, it shows me that it is NOT NULL. So `free` did not work? My code:

```
struct main_struct {
    struct my_file *file;
};

struct my_file {
    char *host;
    int port; // this cannot be malloc'ed and free'ed
};

struct my_file* read_file() {
    FILE *f;
    struct my_file *file;

    //open FILE for reading..

    file = malloc(sizeof(struct my_file)); //allocate memory for my_file struct
    memset(file, 0, sizeof(struct my_file));

    // while loop to read file content..
    // in the loop:
        char *value = line;
        file->host = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(value)); //allocate memory for host member variable
        strncpy(file->host, value, strlen(value)); //assign value to host variable

    return file;
}

int main() {
    struct main_struct *mstr;
    mstr = malloc(sizeof(struct main_struct)); //allocate memory to main_struct
    memset(mstr, 0, sizeof(struct main_struct));

    mstr->my_file = read_file(); //call to read file, allocate mem for my_file struct and the 'host' member variable

    // some code

    // call free here:
    if(mstr->my_file->host != NULL) {
        free(mstr->my_file->host);
    }
    // check if mem has been freed:
    if(mstr->my_file->host == NULL) {
        printf("mstr->my_file->host is NULL, good.\n");
    } else {
        printf("mstr->my_file->host is NOT NULL, bad.\n"); // I see this.
    }

    // I also try to free mstr->my_file:
    if(mstr->my_file != NULL) {
        free(mstr->my_file);
    }
    // check if mem has been freed:
    if(mstr->my_file == NULL) {
        printf("mstr->my_file is NULL, good.\n");
    } else {
        printf("mstr->my_file is NOT NULL, bad.\n"); // I see this.
    }

    // and also mstr itself..
}
```

Am I using the `free` function correctly, because I have seen examples where `free` has been called like this:
`free(&mystruct->myfile->host);` by sending the address of the pointer to free. But I think that the way I am calling free now, is correct..?

Comment: You are calling `free` correctly. What do you expect `free` does?

Comment: `free` is unable to set your pointer variable to `NULL` because it was only passed a *copy* of your variable. Please set it to `NULL` yourself. *by sending the address of the pointer to free* - no by sending the pointer, not its own address.

Comment: Free returns that allocated part of memory from the program's memory space back to the OS. But why is that pointer not NULL, after free has supposedly freed the memory. Is it supposed to be not NULL?

Comment: @John. `free` most certainly does not do that.

Comment: @John. Freeing memory and setting a pointer to `NULL` are two completely different things.

Comment: @John - `free` *cannot* set your variable to `NULL`. To do that it would need a pointer to your pointer.

Comment: And you're also not freeing the right thing here. You allocate a buffer and assign it to `mstr->my_file`, you must therefore free `mstr->my_file`, NOT `mstr->my_file->host`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `mstr`, `mstr->my_file`, and `mstr->my_file->host` are all allocated dynamically.

Comment: Ok, that is where I was confused then, setting a variable/pointer to null and actually freeing allocated memory..

Comment: I also free mstr->my_file, I have added the code.

Comment: In fact, I think that it is better to just call the free() function directly, and not use a wrapper function in which free is called, because the less functions you call, the less copies of the pointers are made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`free(x)` doesn't set `x` no NULL automatically, it just deallocates the memory and leaves `x` pointing to an invalid location. If you want to free `x` you can use a function like

```
void clear(void** ptr) { free(*ptr); *ptr = NULL; }

...

free(&(mstr->my_file->host));
```

Or you can do it manually each time. The comma operator can help here:

```
mstr->my_file->host = (free(mstr->my_file->host), NULL);
```

*Edit*: if you happen to be using glib (and its memory management wrappers), there is [`g_clear_pointer`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-clear-pointer) and [`g_clear_object`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-clear-object) to help with this.

Comment: Oops, you're right, fixed. I usually hide it in a macro where I'm very aggressive about parenthesis, but that has too many caveats to suggest to a beginner.

Comment: I see now that I was confused: freeing =/= setting pointer to NULL.So the memory DOES gets freed in my example.

Comment: Yup. Note that tools like valgrind or AddressSanitizer are great for checking for leaks.  For the latter, just compile with `-fsanitize=address`, you'll get warnings/errors when you leak, try to access invalid memory, etc. Static analyzers can also help; scan-build and cppcheck are open source, but if you want a great commercial tool Coverity is pretty amazing (and they make it available to open source projects for free).

Answer (score 2):

`free(&foo)` is always wrong. You can only `free` pointer values that were returned from `malloc` / `calloc` / `realloc` (and wrappers such as `strdup`). `&foo` is the address of an existing variable (managed by the compiler).

`free(ptr)` will not set `ptr` to `NULL`. In general, a function call `f(x)` cannot modify `x` because C passes arguments by value. It will simply release the memory behind `ptr`, without touching `ptr` itself.

`free(ptr)` is a bit of a special case, because afterwards the value of `ptr` is indeterminate, which means your `if(mstr->my_file->host != NULL)` check actually has undefined behavior (looking at an indeterminate value is not allowed).

See also http://c-faq.com/malloc/ptrafterfree.html.

---

Random comments:

- Never use `strncpy`. It is not a string function (in the sense that it doesn't work with or produce C strings), and its behavior will bite you at some point.
- Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.
- `malloc` + `memset` can be combined by using `calloc` to get zero-initialized memory. (In some cases `calloc` is also much faster than `malloc`/`memset`.)

Comment: "&foo is the address of an existing variable (managed by the compiler)". Had never paid attention to that. +1.

Comment: Nice article, it is clear now: as long as free actually frees memory, there will be no memory leaks. And no checking of pointers that have been freed.